# Get the day name and time on posting automatically using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, time

This will result in a javascript format: **9 Aug, 2012**

```
var month = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12];
var month2 = ["Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"];
var day = postdate.split(-)[2].substring(0,2);
var m = postdate.split(-)[1];
var y = postdate.split(-)[0];
for(var u2=0;u2<month.length;u2++){
if(parseInt(m)==month[u2]) {
m = month2[u2] ; break;
}
}
var daystr = day+ ' ' + m + ', ' + y ;
```

How to add the day name and time in javascript above? 
Ex: **Thursday, 9 Aug, 2012 5:28 PM**

Comment: It would help to see what format `postdate` is in.

Comment: Have you looked at the methods of the `Date` object, e.g., the [`getDay()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDay)? Also, isn't that for loop kind of a complicated way to work out the month? If your `m` variable is expected to be a number between 1 and 12 then what about just using `month2[m-1]`?

Answer (score 0):

`getDay();` will return the dayname
  `getTime()` will return the time in milliscond since 1970.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the day name using `gatDay();`

and here is a function to display time.

```
function displayTime() {
            var currentTime = new Date();
            var currentHours = currentTime.getHours();
            var currentMinutes = currentTime.getMinutes();
            var currentSeconds = currentTime.getSeconds();

            // Pad the minutes and seconds with leading zeros, if required
            currentMinutes = (currentMinutes < 10 ? "0" : "" ) + currentMinutes;
            currentSeconds = (currentSeconds < 10 ? "0" : "" ) + currentSeconds;

            // Choose either "AM" or "PM" as appropriate
            var timeOfDay = (currentHours < 12 ) ? "AM" : "PM";

            // Convert the hours component to 12-hour format if needed
            currentHours = (currentHours > 12 ) ? currentHours - 12 : currentHours;

            // Convert an hours component of "0" to "12"
            currentHours = (currentHours == 0 ) ? 12 : currentHours;

            // Compose the string for display
            var currentTimeString = currentHours + ":" + currentMinutes + " " +currentSeconds+" "+ timeOfDay;

            $("#clock").html(currentTimeString);

        }
```